# Finding extremum of quadratic function divided by $x$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

How can we find the extremum value for the function:
$$f(x) = \frac{-(3x-4)^2}{2x}$$

I plugged this into GeoGeBra and found two extremums, $24$ and $0$, but how can we find it without using a calculator?

I've thought about calculating the extremum of the numerator first, then dividing it by the respective $x$ value, but it obviously don't work in this case.

How can we solve it?

Comment: *When* does that method work?

Comment: It's not defined at $x=0$.  You can see you have a vertical asymptote there,  with one side going to $-\infty$ and the other to $\infty$, so there are no global extremes.  Local extremes you can find with calculus, taking the derivative and setting to 0

Comment: For $x>0$, $\dfrac{(3x-4)^2}{2x}\ge0$, so $f(x)\le0$; for $x<0$, $(3x+4)^2\ge0$, so $(3x-4)^2\ge -48x$, so $f(x)\ge24$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without calculus.

For $x>0$, $\dfrac{(3x-4)^2}{2x}\ge0$, so $f(x)\le0$,

with $f(x)=0$ when $3x-4=0$.

For $x<0$, $(3x+4)^2\ge0$, so $(3x-4)^2\ge-48x$, so $f(x)\ge24$,

with $f(x)=24$ when $3x+4=0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the "$(3x-4)^2\geq-48x$" part: how did you find it?

Comment: $(3x+4)^2-(3x-4)^2=((3x+4)+(3x-4))(3x+4)-(3x-4))=(6x)(-8)=-48x$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\displaystyle-\frac{(3x-4)^2}{2x}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{(3x-4)^2}{2x}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-\frac{2x\frac{d}{dx}(3x-4)^2-(3x-4)^2\frac{d}{dx}2x}{4x^2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{2(3x-4)^2-12x(3x-4)}{4x^2}$

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-\frac{(3x-4)(6x+8)}{4x^2}$

For maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$, we have

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$

$\displaystyle-\frac{(3x-4)(6x+8)}{4x^2}=0$

$x=\frac{4}{3}$ or $ -\frac{4}{3}$

Clearly $x=\frac{4}{3}$ gives$f(x)=0$ and $x=-\frac{4}{3}$ gives $f(x)=24$ which is as you found graphically.